# Using Web API in an MVC Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Web API that is currently being used in java script clients and I would like to use some of the APIs in MVC projects as the data source.

I haven't been able to find information on consuming the Web API from an MVC Class. Maybe I'm just not looking in the right places. Is there a .Net method for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an easy way to POST and GET from RESTful urls (like Web API) check out [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text)

You can do operations like:

```
var resultString = fullUrl.PostJsonToUrl(args);
MyType results = resultString.FromJson<MyType>();
```

Where ...

`args` can be any object (including an anonymous type) and it gets serialized to JSON automatically.

`fullUrl` is just a string with the url you're posting to / getting from.

`MyType` is a class with properties that you're deserializing to.  It needs to match the JSON spec that you're getting back.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a recent version of .NET, then you should simply use the [HttpClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx).

Comment: And if it's not a version that supports HttpClient look at using WebRequest.